# can not resolve symbol R in intellijIdea

Tags: android, xml, gradle

suddenly android studio shows this error `can not resolve symbol R`
this is my `build.gradle`

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.galiyara.sandy.galiyara"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        targetCompatibility 1.8
        sourceCompatibility 1.8
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-selection:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.github.chrisbanes:PhotoView:2.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.8.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.8.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:exifinterface:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.7.0'
}
```

and

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.1'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://jitpack.io"
        }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Manifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="com.galiyara.sandy.galiyara">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_WALLPAPER"/>

    <application
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
            android:supportsRtl="true"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <provider
                android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
                android:authorities="com.galiyara.sandy.galiyara.provider"
                android:exported="false"
                android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                    android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                    android:resource="@xml/paths"/>
        </provider>

        <!-- Main activity -->
        <activity
                android:name=".MainActivity"
                android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <!-- Albums activity -->
        <activity android:name=".AlbumsActivity"/>
        <!-- Image view activity -->
        <activity android:name=".ImageViewActivity"/>
        <!-- Image cropper activity -->
        <activity android:name="com.theartofdev.edmodo.cropper.CropImageActivity"
                  android:theme="@style/Base.Theme.AppCompat"/>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: This is very common. . . Just go to **File > Invalidate Cache / Restart** and click on the "Invalidate and Restart" button.

Comment: Already tried..but no success

Comment: Did you **clean project** then **rebuild the project** and then **sync project with gradle files** as well?

Comment: Yes..many times

Comment: Well do you remember if you did something before this happened? Maybe changed an xml file? Maybe moved an activity file? Or did you just start up the project and this happened? Have you even imported R?

Comment: i didn't change any of xml files..i changed gradle in gradle>. properties toh latest 3.10

Comment: What? If you are talking about your gradle version defined in your gradle properties, the latest gradle version is not 3.10. Also, I can see you are using a gradle plugin 3.3.1 so for that you need a gradle version of at least 4.10.1+. You can see all available Gradle Distributions [here](https://services.gradle.org/distributions/)

Comment: Sorry my mistake yes gradle version 4.10.1

Comment: So i should update my libraries..?

Comment: Can u please add manifest file code also?

Comment: sorry for late response, i was sleeping. There is nothing wrong with your Gradle files. Manually delete your build folder and rebuild it to see if you get a more specific error. Also, go through your res folder and see if you have any deprecated stuff that is preventing your R.java from being built. Usually android studio should log these errors but you never know.

Comment: @Zumbarlal Saindane added

Comment: Deleted build folder and checked all res files no deprecated stuff there....no success yet..

Comment: @veeru_sandy
add

 "buildToolsVersion '28.0.3' 

&
add at top level gradle file
dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0-alpha02'
        

    } sync gradle & check it

Answer (score 0):

Go ***File*** > ***Settings*** > ***Buid, Execution, Deployment*** > ***Gradle***

Check *Gradle Home* has the latest version **gradle-4.10.1**.

```
D:/Gradle/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-4.10.1-all/byrf7c6xk4p2imgx1wxxfgf3t/gradle-4.10.1
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Add `buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'`

& Update top level gradle file as:

```
dependencies { classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0-alpha02' }
```

Update below libraries

```
implementation 'com.github.chrisbanes:PhotoView:2.0.0'
implementation 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.7.0'
```

to latest version

```
implementation 'com.github.chrisbanes:PhotoView:2.3.0'
implementation 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.8.0'
```

And for `image-cropper` library 

Add this line to your Proguard config file

```
-keep class android.support.v7.widget.** { *; }
```

and also check there any conflicts between libraries. If its gives any error at gradle sync just add the error, we will solve it.

Also please check your `strings.xml` or any other `.xml file under "values"` folder if there is syntax error

And Please use the latest version of `Android Studio`

Comment: now the error is
`
Manifest merger failed : Attribute application@appComponentFactory value=(android.support.v4.app.CoreComponentFactory) from [com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-91
 is also present at [androidx.core:core:1.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-86 value=(androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory).
 Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"' to <application> element at AndroidManifest.xml:9:5-44:19 to override.
`

Comment: pls update all libraries  which showing update available warning.

Comment: Put these flags in your `gradle.properties`

    android.useAndroidX=true


    android.enableJetifier=true

and check it

Comment: after adding **new addition all methods are now red(can not resolve)
like- setContentView,findViewById.....
MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity also not found

Comment: ok then pls remove android.useAndroidX=true android.enableJetifier=true

Comment: did and now same error can not resolve symbol R and manifest merger failed

Comment: can u pls remove implementation 'com.android.support:exifinterface:28.0.0' from your gradle and sync project again

Comment: use this version library implementation 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.7.0'

Comment: implementation 'com.github.chrisbanes:PhotoView:2.1.4'

Comment: now manifest merger failed solved..
but can not resolve symbol R is still

Comment: still there now the problem is can not resolve symbol R

Comment: can u connect using https://zoom.us/signin ,
so I can see what is the exact problem